# Convert SAS read-in file into SQL

Tags: sql, sas

I am trying to read a .DAT file into SQL. The agency data provider supplied read-in code in SAS here (https://www.health.ny.gov/statistics/sparcs/docs/ip_v2.sas). I would like to read this data into a secure SQL database and was wondering if anyone could help me translate this SAS code into SQL? Here's the start:

```
OPTIONS NOCENTER NODATE FORMDLIM=' ' compress=yes pagesize=50;
%let yr=11;

/**** READ IN FILE ******* No Check for HexDec ****/
data IUM;
  infile eium truncover lrecl=2500 PAD ignoredoseof /*obs=10000*/ ; 
  INPUT
    @0016   ordr    $char3.
    @0001   RECDTL  $char2500.
  ;
```

Further down it is specifying the position and length of the the columns, but not the data type. Any SAS users out there feeling smart and generous?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Which SQL implementation?

Comment: Code conversion is explicitly off topic, sorry.  Please feel free to make an attempt yourself (reading the  extensive documentation on the subject perhaps) and then come back if you have specific questions.

Comment: That's not a very straightforward question here tbh. The data is pretty simple but there's actually multiple imports and conversions inside the single program there. If you're not qualified, I would suggest hiring a contractor for this one, because it's not just a quick translation. It's not hard, but it would take a few hours to document the steps at minimum.

Comment: The HTML source of the link shows a SAS program dealing with multiple files and multiple record types within a file.  Depending on the amount of data, your company and pay grade, it might be cheaper to buy a SAS license with *Connect  to SQL Server* than the cost for you to rewrite the processing as a SQL Server import script.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! It's good to know that this isn't super simple, I will look into consulting with a SAS expert. Much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

What is there to translate?  The `@xxxx` is saying what column to start in, then you have the variable name and the informat to use to read it. SAS only has two data types, fixed length character strings and floating point numbers.  Any informat that starts with a `$` will generate a character variable. Others will generate a number.  Some obvious informats will generate numbers that can be interpreted as dates, times or datetime (timestamp) values. Such as `date9.`, `time8.` or `datetime20.`. But also other informats for other ways of representing dates in text format, like `YYMMDD.` , `MMDDYY.` or `DDMMYY.`.

SAS will define the order of the variables in the dataset based on when you first reference them in the code. So ORDR will be defined in the database before RECDTL even though the latter appears first in the text file (column 1 versus column 16).